# Como ingresar estos datos a Mysql por Php, cambiendo unos datos dentro de un array a Fecha

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Buenas podrían ayudarme con un código?, no soy muy bueno con php.

 Lo que sucede es que tengo un array con estos datos:

```
array = {manzana,roja,mercado,22/02/1994,mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos},
        {pera,verde,supermercado,24/04/2019,mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos},
        {platano,amarillo,supermercado,23/01/2015,mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos},
```

Los quiero ingresar en una tabla de Mysqli por medio de php, lo intente de esta forma.

```
foreach($nuevoArreglo as $params)
{
$var = $params[3];
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
$datetime = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO tabla(fiel1, field2, fiel3, FECHA, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10) VALUES
                         ('$params[0]', '$params[1]', '$params[2]', '$datatime', '$params[4]', '$params[5]', '$params[6]', '$params[7]', '$params[8]', '$params[9]')");  
}
```

Al momento de checarlo en las tablas de Mysqli, guardo tal y como quiero los datos, pero la Fecha solo tomo la 1era y la repitia, es decir, guarda algo como esto:

```
            {manzana,roja,mercado,22/02/1994,mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos},
            {pera,verde,supermercado,22/02/1994,mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos},
            {platano,amarillo,supermercado,22/02/1994,mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos, mas datos},
```

No sabría si es la mejor forma de hacer esto, pero como no se mucho de Php es lo que eh logrado. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta `$date = str_replace('/', '-', $params[3]);`

Comment: Muchas gracias y disculpe, corregi el codigo, puesto que utilizo la variable $var que esta ya tiene asignado el $params[3] como usted me indica, aun asi, lo que hace es que agarra la primera fecha del array y reemplaza las demas.

Answer (score 0):

para mí el error está en tu array, que debería ser multidimensional y me parece que la solución estaría en armarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$nuevoArreglo=array(
    array("manzana","roja","mercado","22/02/1994","mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos"),
    array("pera","verde","supermercado","24/04/2019","mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos"),
    array("platano","amarillo","supermercado","23/01/2015","mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos", "mas datos")
);
```

De esta manera si haces un `echo $var;` dentro del `for` debería mostrarte las 3 fechas.